# How to iterate a function with strings over a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I want to get the Jaccard Similarity between my dataframe and the base. The issue is I need it for 500+ rows and I either get the error message: **"too many values to unpack"**, **'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'** or the functions compares the base witht the dataframe as a whole.

Alternative A:

```
sentences = pd.Series(df.sentence)
sentences = sentences.str.replace('[^A-z ]','').str.replace(' +',' ').str.strip()
splitwords = [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(sentence) ) for sentence in sentences ]
print(splitwords)
sentence = df.sentence
def Jaccard_Similarity(base, sentence):
    for i, row in sentence.iterrows():
        a = set(word for word in base)
        b = set(word for word in df.sentence())
        c = a.intersection(b)
        return(float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c)), a, b)
Jaccard_Similarity(base, sentence)
```

Alternative B:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['sentence']), axis=1)
print(df)

def Jaccard_Similarity(bas, df):
    for row in df.iterrows(df):
        a = set(word for word in base)
        b = set(word for word in df)
        c = a.intersection(b)
        return(float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c)), a, b)
Jaccard_Similarity(base, df)
```

Data:

```
base = ['Tom', 'eats', 'apple']    
df = (["Tom eats an apple"],
          ["Tom eats a pineapple"],
          ["Eva eats an apple"],
          ["Eva eats a pineapple"],
         columns = 'sentence')
```

***EDIT:***

```
   base = set(base.lower().split()) 
   df = set(df.lower().split())

def Jaccard_Similarity(base, df): 
    intersection = base.intersection(df)
    union = base.union(df)
    return float(len(intersection)) / len(union)
```

Comment: FYI: If you planned to remove all chars other than ASCII letters and spaces with `'[^A-z ]'`, you should know that `[A-z]` [matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). You need `[^a-zA-Z ]`

Comment: Yes, ideally it would also erase some numbers at the beginning which do not contribute to a successful classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I'll add the explanation later need some work to do.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords # to remove stopwords

base = ['Tom', 'eats', 'apple']
base = [item.lower() for item in base]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
list1 = [["Tom eats an apple"],
          ["Tom eats a pineapple"],
          ["Eva eats an apple"],
          ["Eva eats a pineapple"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns= ['sentence'])
df = df.sentence.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
df = df.apply(
    lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words]
)
b = df.apply(set)
a = set(base)
c =  b.apply(lambda x : a.intersection(x))
len_a_b = b.apply(lambda x : len(x) +  len(a))
len_c  = c.apply(lambda x : len(x))
dict1 = {'length' : len_c / (len_a_b - len_c) , 'b' : b , 'c' : c}
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df['a'] = np.NAN
df['a'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: a)
print(df)
```

**output -**

```
   length                       b                   c                   a
0     1.0      {apple, eats, tom}  {apple, eats, tom}  {apple, eats, tom}
1     0.5  {eats, tom, pineapple}         {eats, tom}  {apple, eats, tom}
2     0.5      {apple, eats, eva}       {apple, eats}  {apple, eats, tom}
3     0.2  {eats, pineapple, eva}              {eats}  {apple, eats, tom}
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me better results. How can I exclude stopwords and lower()?

Comment: Using ```df = df.str.replace('[^A-z ]','').str.replace(' +',' ').str.strip()``` gives me: **AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'**

Comment: using lower() gives me this: **AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
** even though it isn't a series, is it?

Comment: Used list comprehension to convert into lower case.

Comment: and imported stopwords from ntlk.corpus to remove stopwords

Comment: Okay, but when I exported the new df to CSV there are still capital letters.

Comment: Also, the values for the very same words of just 0.375 seem too low.

Comment: I'll suggest getting the chunk of data and adding print statements to see  where you're going wrong